# Number of complex roots for the system of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, groebner-bases

I have a system of algebraic equations.
For example:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x^2 y + 2 x y + 2 &= 0,\\
y^3 + 2 x + 1 &= 0.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
(In my problem the system contains 16 equations of degrees 1–3).

I need to know the number of complex roots (the system in question has a finite number of roots).

I believe, the number of roots can be determined using `GroebnerBasis`. 
But what is the most elegant way to do it?

Comment: Your question would get more attention if you provide _Mathematica_ code instead of $\LaTeX$ :)

Comment: `{x^2 y + 2 x y + 2 == 0, y^3 + 2 x + 1 == 0}`   But the question is not about solving this particular system.

Comment: @bcp Getting help is sometimes about making it easy for potential answerers to verify their ideas on your illustrative example.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest method, that will usually be correct, is to just use `NSolve`.

```
polys = {x^2 y + 2 x y + 2, y^3 + 2 x + 1};
Length[NSolve[polys]]

(* Out[421]= 7 *)
```

Below is from code I have used for solution counting and related (it is related to code inside `NSolve`, to answer the question of "Why not just use `NSolve`?"). Some is also used in [this MSE response](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5537/51). The underlying method is described in Gröbner Bases: A Computational Approach to Commutative Algebra, by T. Becker and V. Weispfenning (with H. Kredel).

```
normalSet[elist_List, maxlist_, nvars_Integer] /; 
  Length[elist] == nvars := 
 Module[{jj, indices, iterators}, indices = Array[jj, {nvars}];
  iterators = Table[{indices[[j]], 0, maxlist[[j]] - 1}, {j, nvars}];
  Flatten[Table[indices, Evaluate[Apply[Sequence, iterators]]], 
   nvars - 1]]

getRoofTuples[elist_, height_] := 
 Module[{len = Length[elist], expvec, expvecs, tt, rest}, 
  expvecs = tt[];
  Do[expvec = elist[[jj]];
   If[expvec[[height]] =!= 
      0 && (height === 1 || Max[Take[expvec, height - 1]] === 0), 
    expvecs = tt[expvec, expvecs]], {jj, len}];
  expvecs = Apply[List, Flatten[expvecs, Infinity, tt]];
  rest = Complement[elist, expvecs];
  expvecs = Map[Drop[#, height - 1] &, expvecs];
  {expvecs, rest}]

isUnder[t1_, t2_] := Apply[And, Thread[t1 <= t2]]

hitRoof[tup_, roofs_] := 
 Module[{jj, len = Length[roofs]}, 
  For[jj = 1, jj <= len, jj++, 
   If[isUnder[roofs[[jj]], tup], Return[True]]];
  False]

normalSet[elist_List, maxes_, nvars_Integer] := 
 Module[{tuples, ntups, tuple, ntup, mixedexpons, tt}, 
  mixedexpons = 
   Select[elist, (Max[Apply[Sequence, #]] != Apply[Plus, #]) &];
  tuples = Table[{j}, {j, 0, maxes[[nvars]] - 1}];
  Do[{roofs, mixedexpons} = getRoofTuples[mixedexpons, jj];
   ntups = tt[];
   Do[tuple = tuples[[kk]];
    ntups = tt[Prepend[tuple, 0], ntups];
    Do[ntup = Prepend[tuple, mm];
     If[hitRoof[ntup, roofs], Break[], ntups = tt[ntup, ntups]], {mm, 
      maxes[[jj]] - 1}], {kk, Length[tuples]}];
   tuples = Flatten[ntups, Infinity, tt], {jj, nvars - 1, 1, -1}];
  Sort[Apply[List, tuples]]]

solutionSetSize[polys_, vars_] := 
 Catch[Module[{lv = Length[vars], leadvecs, dtl, maxes, nset, 
    pureterms},
   gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, vars, 
     MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic];
   dtl = First[
     GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[gb, vars, 
      MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic]];
   leadvecs = Map[#[[1, 1]] &, dtl];
   pureterms = Select[leadvecs, Count[#, a_ /; a =!= 0] === 1 &];
   If[Length[pureterms] < lv, Throw[Infinity]];
   maxes = Apply[Plus, pureterms];
   nset = normalSet[leadvecs, maxes, lv];
   Throw[Length[nset]]
   ]]
```

Back to the example:

```
solutionSetSize[polys, {x, y}]

(* Out[423]= 7 *)
```

Comment: In ```normalSet[elist_List, maxes_, nvars_Integer]```, what does ```normalSet``` do, what is a typical ```elist```, and what sort of thing is ```maxes```?  Can you give an example?  TIA

Comment: @atat Given a list of polynomials and variables, `solutionSetSize` counts solutions by computing the normal set (with respect to a term order). I suspect that's what was wanted for the "standard monomials" in your recent question. Maybe I misinterpreted though.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GroebnerBasis.html) is very instructive.

For your particular example:

```
gb = GroebnerBasis[{x^2 y + 2 x y + 2, y^3 + 2 x + 1}, {x, y}]
```

Finding roots:

```
sol = N@Solve[gb[[1]] == 0, y]
```

=>{{y -> -1.29819}, {y -> -0.871821 - 1.29622 I}, {y -> -0.871821 + 
    1.29622 I}, {y -> 0.274176 - 1.20102 I}, {y -> 
   0.274176 + 1.20102 I}, {y -> 1.24674 - 0.331078 I}, {y -> 
   1.24674 + 0.331078 I}}

```
sol2 = Solve[gb[[2]] == 0, x] /. sol
```

=>  {{{x -> 0.593927}}, {{x -> -2.36593 + 0.388879 I}}, {{x -> -2.36593 - 
     0.388879 I}}, {{x -> 0.0829231 - 0.730783 I}}, {{x -> 
    0.0829231 + 0.730783 I}}, {{x -> -1.26396 + 
     0.753779 I}}, {{x -> -1.26396 - 0.753779 I}}}

Just for fun showing real root:

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Thread[{x^2 y + 2 x y + 2, y^3 + 2 x + 1} == 0], {x, -10, 
  10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, 
   Point[{{First[x /. First[sol2]], First[y /. sol]}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: So the question is whether I can determine the number of roots without actually finding all of them. (e.g. if I had only one single-variable polynomial equation, I would take its degree as the answer)