# Calculating the basis set of quotient spaces

Tags: polynomials, group-theory

Having a polynomial $f(x,y)$, I would like to compute the following quantity
\begin{equation*}
{\mathbb C}[X,Y,Z]/\langle f_{x}, f_{y}, f_{z} \rangle,
\end{equation*}
where $f_{x},f_{y},f_{z}$ are, respectively, derivatives of $f$ with respect to $x$, $y$ and $z$.

For $f=2x^2 + 4 y^3 + 5 z^5$, $\langle f_{x}, f_{y}, f_{z} \rangle =\{ x,y^2,z^4\} $. I have implemented this as

```
f = 2 x^2 + 4 y^3 + 5 z^5
vars = {x, y, z}
fp = D[f, {vars}]
monomialList[poly_, vars_] := 
 Times @@ (vars^#) & /@ CoefficientRules[poly, vars][[All, 1]]
Flatten[Table[monomialList[fp[[i]], {x, y, z}], {i, 1, 3, 1}]]
```

The next step is to obtain the basis of the quotient space, which should be $\{1,z,z^2,z^3,y,yz,yz^2,yz^3\}$.
Do you have any suggestions on computing this set in Mathematica?
As I should carry out these calculations for several polynomials, having a generic answer for this question is ideal.

Update: the length of this set is known as the Milnor number. Here is a screenshot of three different polynomials whose Milnor numbers are obtained using the [Singular package](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/4-0-3/sing_1637.htm).
[image]

Comment: For harder cases you can crib from [code for counting the solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51913/51). Just toss the final line that takes the length of the normal set, and instead return the normal set itself.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau This is very interesting. I have test that on ``` poly = x z + y^2
Length[basisSet[poly]]
solutionSetSize[poly, Variables[poly]]``` and I got an empty set and an $\infty$. I again get $\infty$ in the output for the example polynomial in my question. Do you know why?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau (+1) This is very interesting. If I apply it to the jacobian of my polynomial, it generates all the exponents of the set. I should figure out how to bring these exponents to polynomials. Thank you for sharing this exciting solution.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it was the exponent vectors that I generate. You can do something like Map[vars^#&, exponvecs] (apologies for not formatting or testing, I’m traveling with just a phone).

Comment: Also I’ll look into the misbehaving example when I’m back at work.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you very much for being helpful.

Comment: @Shasa, since there seems to be some misunderstandings, I would suggest you to include more examples of polynomials and expected solutions into your question :)

Comment: Good suggestion! I will try to do so.

Comment: Also I recall I had to make changes over the years when bugs or incompatibilities were found and fixed (often by others). The most recent can be found [in the WFR](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CountPolynomialSolutions/?i=CountPolynomialSolutions&searchapi=https%3A%2F%2Fresources.wolframcloud.com%2FFunctionRepository%2Fsearch). Grab the author notebook if you get a chance, and modify as already mentioned to get the normal set instead of its length. If this still messes up then I’ll need to do a bit of debugging.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, I will check that out. Thank you for sharing the link.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, the code in the shared link works fine with all the polynomials I had in mind. So, first, thank you, and second, if you could write your comment as an answer, I could accept that so that this thread is set as solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is code for producing a monomial basis set for a polynomial algebra with a finite dimensional vector space. It is taken from the resource function [CountPolynomialSolutions](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CountPolynomialSolutions) with very minor modification to return the basis set.

I will point out that this basis set is not unique. The one returned arises from a particular Groebner basis computation on the input polynomials. Also, in the case where the vector space generators are not finite it returns `{1}`. And if the system is inconsistent it returns `{}`.

```
Clear[PolynomialAlgebraGenerators]

headsTable[elist_List, maxlist_, nvars_Integer] /; 
  Length[elist] == nvars :=
 Module[{jj, indices, iterators},
  (* Easy case: 
  all exponent vectors surrounding the normal set are "pure," that is,
  unmixed. *)
  indices = Array[jj, {nvars}];
  iterators = Table[{indices[[j]], 0, maxlist[[j]] - 1}, {j, nvars}];
  Flatten[Table[indices, Evaluate[Apply[Sequence, iterators]]], 
   nvars - 1]]

getRoofTuples[elist_, height_] := 
 Module[{len = Length[elist], expvec, expvecs, tt, rest},
  (* Tricky but efficient method. 
  Similar to that of Corless reference. *)
  expvecs = tt[];
  Do[expvec = elist[[jj]];
   If[expvec[[height]] =!= 
      0 && (height === 1 || Max[Take[expvec, height - 1]] === 0),
    expvecs = tt[expvec, expvecs]], {jj, len}];
  expvecs = Apply[List, Flatten[expvecs, Infinity, tt]];
  rest = Complement[elist, expvecs];
  expvecs = Map[Drop[#, height - 1] &, expvecs];
  {expvecs, rest}]

isUnder[t1_, t2_] := Apply[And, Thread[t1 <= t2]]

hitRoof[tup_, roofs_] := 
 Catch[Module[{jj, len = Length[roofs]}, 
   For[jj = 1, jj <= len, jj++, 
    If[isUnder[roofs[[jj]], tup], Throw[True, "hR"]]];
   False], "hR"]

headsTable[elist_List, maxes_, nvars_Integer] := 
 Module[{tuples, ntups, tuple, ntup, mixedexpons, tt, roofs}, 
  mixedexpons = 
   Select[elist, (Max[Apply[Sequence, #]] != Apply[Plus, #]) &];
  tuples = Table[{j}, {j, 0, maxes[[nvars]] - 1}];
  Do[{roofs, mixedexpons} = getRoofTuples[mixedexpons, jj];
   ntups = tt[];
   Do[tuple = tuples[[kk]];
    ntups = tt[Prepend[tuple, 0], ntups];
    Do[ntup = Prepend[tuple, mm];
     If[hitRoof[ntup, roofs], Break[], ntups = tt[ntup, ntups]];
     , {mm, maxes[[jj]] - 1}]
    , {kk, Length[tuples]}];
   tuples = Flatten[ntups, Infinity, tt], {jj, nvars - 1, 1, -1}];
  Sort[Apply[List, tuples]]]

Options[PolynomialAlgebraGenerators] = {WorkingPrecision -> Automatic};

PolynomialAlgebraGenerators[polys_List, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[PolynomialAlgebraGenerators]] :=
 PolynomialAlgebraGenerators[polys, Variables[polys], opts]

PolynomialAlgebraGenerators[opoly_?(! ListQ[#] &), 
  var_?(! ListQ[#] &), 
  opts : OptionsPattern[PolynomialAlgebraGenerators]] := 
 PolynomialAlgebraGenerators[{opoly}, {var}, opts]

PolynomialAlgebraGenerators[opolys_, vars_List, 
   OptionsPattern[PolynomialAlgebraGenerators]] /; 
  AllTrue[Map[PolynomialQ[#, vars] &, opolys], TrueQ] := 
 Catch[Module[
   {polys = opolys, domain, wprec, params, gb, dtl, leadvecs, 
    pureterms, nv = Length[vars], orderedvars, maxexpons, expons, 
    monorder = (MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic)},
   wprec = OptionValue[WorkingPrecision];
   If[wprec === Automatic,
    If[Internal`EffectivePrecision[polys] === Infinity,
     domain = CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions
     ,(*else finite precision, 
     so substitute numeric values for any parameters*)
     wprec = Internal`EffectivePrecision[polys];
     domain = CoefficientDomain -> InexactNumbers[wprec];
     params = 
      DeleteCases[Complement[Variables[polys], vars], _?NumericQ];
     polys = 
      polys /. 
       Thread[params -> 
         RandomReal[{-10, 10}, Length[params], 
          WorkingPrecision -> wprec]];
     ]
    ,(*else not Automatic*)
    If[Internal`EffectivePrecision[polys] === Infinity && 
       wprec === Infinity,
      domain = CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions
      ,
      If[wprec === MachinePrecision, wprec = $MachinePrecision];
      domain = CoefficientDomain -> InexactNumbers[wprec];
      params = 
       DeleteCases[Complement[Variables[polys], vars], _?NumericQ];
      polys = 
       polys /. 
        Thread[params -> 
          RandomReal[{-10, 10}, Length[params], 
           WorkingPrecision -> wprec]];
      ];
    ];
   orderedvars = 
    Last[GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[polys, vars, Sort -> True,
       domain, monorder]];
   gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, orderedvars, Sort -> False, domain, 
     monorder];
   If[Length[gb] == 1 && NumericQ[gb[[1]]], Throw[{}, "CPS"]];
   Quiet[
    dtl = First[
      GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[gb, orderedvars, 
       Sort -> False, domain, monorder]]];
   leadvecs = Map[#[[1, 1]] &, dtl];
   pureterms = Select[leadvecs, Count[#, a_ /; a =!= 0] === 1 &];
   If[Length[pureterms] < nv, Throw[{1}, "CPS"]];
   maxexpons = Apply[Plus, pureterms];
   expons = headsTable[leadvecs, maxexpons, nv];
   Map[Inner[Power, orderedvars, #, Times] &, expons]
   ], "CPS"]
```

Here is the original example in the post.

```
f = 2 x^2 + 4 y^3 + 5 z^5;
vars = {x, y, z};
fp = D[f, {vars}];
gens = PolynomialAlgebraGenerators[fp, vars]

(* Out[81]= {1, z, z^2, z^3, y, y z, y z^2, y z^3} *)
```

Here is a case where apparently we disagree with the program Singular (assuming I transcribed the system correctly).

```
poly = x^7 + y^7 + (x - y)^2*x^2*y^2 + z^2;
derivs = Grad[poly, {x, y, z}];
gens = PolynomialAlgebraGenerators[Expand@derivs, {x, y, z}]
Length[gens]

(* Out[96]= {1, y, y^2, y^3, y^4, y^5, x, x y, x y^2, x y^3, x y^4, 
 x y^5, x^2, x^2 y, x^2 y^2, x^2 y^3, x^2 y^4, x^2 y^5, x^3, x^3 y, 
 x^3 y^2, x^3 y^3, x^3 y^4, x^3 y^5, x^4, x^4 y, x^4 y^2, x^4 y^3, 
 x^4 y^4, x^4 y^5, x^5, x^5 y, x^5 y^2, x^5 y^3, x^5 y^4, x^5 y^5}

Out[97]= 36 *)
```

This is in accord with CountPolynomialSolutions (as it better be).

```
ResourceFunction["CountPolynomialSolutions"][derivs == 0, {x, y, z}]

(* Out[73]= 36 *)
```

But as shown in the original post, Singular claims the count should be 28.

Comment: (+1)Thank you for sharing this solution and for adding further comparisons

Answer (score 4):

I do't think [@Domen's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/295479/26598) is quite correct. Take, for example,

```
basisSet[(x + y)^3]
(*    {1, y, x, x y}    *)
```

which I don't think is a correct answer: the argument $(x+y)^3$ is cubic in the variables and therefore the resulting basis polynomials should all be linear in the variables. But $x y$ is quadratic, hence something is wrong.

I'd propose a slightly different method that gives the same results as @Domen's in many cases, but gets the correlations between variables more correct:

```
basisSetR[f_] := Module[{F, p, b, e},
    (* the list of derivative polynomials *)
    F = D[f, {Variables[f]}];
    (* the LCM of these, decomposed into factors and their powers *)
    p = DeleteCases[FactorList[PolynomialLCM @@ F], {_?NumericQ, _}];
    (* make all combinations of these factors *)
    If[p == {}, {1},
        {b, e} = Transpose[p];
        (Times @@ (b^#)) & /@ Tuples[Range[0, #] & /@ (e - 1)]]]
```

The OP's example is solved correctly:

```
basisSetR[2 x^2 + 4 y^3 + 5 z^5]
(*    {1, z, z^2, z^3, y, y z, y z^2, y z^3}    *)
```

Let's try the above example again: it now gives only zeroth- and first-order basis polynomials,

```
basisSetR[(x + y)^3]
(*    {1, x + y}    *)
```

Some more edge cases:

```
basisSetR[x z + y^2]
(*    {1}    *)

basisSetR[1]
(*    {1}    *)

basisSetR[x]
(*    {1}    *)

basisSetR[x^2]
(*    {1}    *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also think that Domen's answer should be improved. Daniel's suggested link looks better for more generic cases. I have tried your answer on ```poly = x^3 + x y^2``` the output should be $\{1,x,y,x^2\}$ or $\{ 1,x,y,y^{2}\}$ [This is what I get from Daniel's suggetion]. From your code, I get $\{1 \}$. But your answer beats Daniel's suggestion when it comes to $poly=(x+y)^3$ as I get $\infty$ from Daniel's suggestion.

Comment: Hmm yes, my solution needs improvement.

Comment: But first, I think I need some more clarity. What is the correct solution for $(x+y)^2$? Shouldn't the correct solution be $\{1, x-y\}$ instead of just $\{1\}$?

Comment: The length of the final set is the Milnor number, which can become infinite. I have checked the Milnor number of $(x+y)^2$ in the SINGULAR package, and it gives $\infty$. I have tried two more examples in the screenshot added to the main question.

Comment: Hold on. If the polynomial is not squarefree then the gradient vanishes on a dimensional set, so infinity is correct there.

Answer (score 2):

```
basisSet[f_] := Module[{vars, fp, maxExponents},
  vars = Variables[f];
  fp = D[f, {vars}]; 
  maxExponents = MapThread[Exponent[#1, #2] &, {fp, vars}];
  Times @@@ (vars^# & /@ Tuples[Range[0, # - 1] & /@ maxExponents])
  ]

f = 2 x^2 + 4 y^3 + 5 z^5;
basisSet[f]
(* {1, z, z^2, z^3, y, y z, y z^2, y z^3} *)
```

Comment: (+1) This is great. Thank you, Domen.

Comment: Please check for some edge cases ... For example, what should be the output of `basisSet[x]`? Is `{}` correct or should it be `{1}`?

Comment: Sure! Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Shasa, please unselect my answer as accepted – I don't think I can improve it in any simple way to make it work for all cases :)

Comment: I have unaccepted that. Thank you, @Domen, anyway, for your effort.