# Puiseux series for algebraic curves

Tags: polynomials, series-expansion

Has anyone implemented a function in Mathematica that computes [Puiseux expansions of algebraic curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series#Puiseux_expansion_of_algebraic_curves_and_functions)?

Using something like

```
Series[y /. Solve[poly == 0, y], {x, x0, order}]
```

where "poly" is a polynomial expression in x and y works as long as poly is sufficiently low degree or x0 avoids a branch point.

The right way to do it would probably be via the [Newton-Puiseux algorithm](http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.4674) but I could only find [Maple code](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~hoeij/compalg/algcurves.html) to do it.

Comment: This would also lead to another approach to computing the genus of an algebraic curve http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5381

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the new in M12 function [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) for this. For example, suppose the polynomial is:

```
SeedRandom[1]
poly = x^Range[0, 5].RandomInteger[1, {6, 6}].y^Range[0,5]
```

> 1 + x^3 + (1 + x + x^3) y + (1 + x + x^5) y^3 + (x^4 + x^5) y^4 + x^2 y^5

Then, using [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve):

```
AsymptoticSolve[poly == 0, y, {x, 0, 3}] //N
```

> {{y -> -0.682328 + 0.417238 x - 0.206844 x^2 - 
>       0.143415 x^3}, {y -> (0.341164 - 
>         1.16154 I) - (0.208619 - 0.183825 I) x + (0.603422 - 
>          0.710109 I) x^2 - (0.928292 - 0.263678 I) x^3}, {y -> (0.341164 + 
>         1.16154 I) - (0.208619 + 0.183825 I) x + (0.603422 + 
>          0.710109 I) x^2 - (0.928292 + 0.263678 I) x^3}, {y -> (0. + 0.5 I) + (
>       0. + 1. I)/x - (0. + 0.625 I) x}, {y -> (0. - 0.5 I) - (0. + 1. I)/
>       x + (0. + 0.625 I) x}}

I used `N` to avoid worrying about how to format root objects.