# Easy upper and lower bounds for curve genus in Mathematica

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I am writing a Mathematica code in which I need, at some point, to compute genus of a lot of curves given by polynomial equations in 2 variables in affine coordinates. Unfortunately, this is possible in Maple but not in Mathematica. So I currently copy thousands of equations produced by Mathematica to Maple, compute genus there, copy the result back, and continue computations. This is not easy.

From this previous question [Computing the genus of an algebraic curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5381/computing-the-genus-of-an-algebraic-curve) I understood that computing genus exactly for all curves is quite difficult. It would help if I would have some easy code for computing upper and lower bounds for curve genus in Mathematica. I guess that for most curves this task should be quite easy, and the code would return matching bounds. I could then identify (hopefully small number of) equations with non-matching bounds and check them in Maple.

An obvious upper bound is the genus degree formula, and it is already tight for many equations. Is it possible to get better upper bound with easy code? Also, can we easily compute lower bound that is good in most cases?

Comment: How about computing the Puiseux expansions around all singular points $S$ via the built-in AsymptoticSolve function  and then use the formula $$ g=1/2 \sum_S r_i-d+1$$.  Maybe provide an example function.

Comment: I believe an  obvious lower bound of a random (generic) algebraic curve would be $$g_L=\frac{T-P}{2}-d+1$$ with $T$ the total number of singular points and $P$ the total number of un-ramified poles.  Both $T$ and $P$ are easily computed for moderate degree curves (under 30 or so).  Might be interesting to check this (hypothesis) with a large number of sample curves.

Comment: Can anyone help with Mathematica code for these "easily computed" bounds? I did some search online how to do this in Mathematica but it is still unclear for me.

Comment: Also, when you write "obvious lower bound of a random (generic) algebraic curve" do you mean that this is a lower bound for ALL curves which is tight for random curves, or that for some curves this is not even a lower bound at all?

Comment: After thinking about it for a while I propose $g_L$ is the lower bound for any algebraic curve of degree $d\geq 2$.  Try and find one which is lower. How about editing your post above with a typical (polynomial) function $f(w,z)=0$ whose algebraic curve $w(z)$ of degree $d$ you wish to compute the genus, then look up and review three Mathematical functions: Resultant, NSolve, and AsymptoticSolve.

Comment: Also I should mention if you don't post some Mathematica code in your post above showing some attempt at solving this problem the moderators may close your thread for lack of attempt. So try and figure out how to solve for the singular points of some simple $f(z,w)=0$ by NSolve'ing for the zeros of the Resultant of $f$ and $f_w$ and posting the results..